# OpenCV digit OCR

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, knn

I am trying to build a simple Sudoku grabber that scans a Sudoku image and extracts digits in the order (`0` for blank). I have successfully extracted 81 box approximately.

**SCREEN_SHOT of cells 9x9**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2t6U.png]

**CODE**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import cv2.cv as cv
import tesseract



def rectify(h):
        h = h.reshape((4,2))
        hnew = np.zeros((4,2),dtype = np.float32)

        add = h.sum(1)
        hnew[0] = h[np.argmin(add)]
        hnew[2] = h[np.argmax(add)]

        diff = np.diff(h,axis = 1)
        hnew[1] = h[np.argmin(diff)]
        hnew[3] = h[np.argmax(diff)]

        return hnew

img=cv2.imread('sudoku.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,1,1,11,2)


contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

biggest = None
max_area = 0
for i in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(i)
        if area > 100:
                peri = cv2.arcLength(i,True)
                approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i,0.02*peri,True)
                if area > max_area and len(approx)==4:
                        biggest = approx
                        max_area = area
cv2.drawContours(img, biggest, -1, (0,255,0), 8)

biggest=rectify(biggest)

h = np.array([ [0,0],[449,0],[449,449],[0,449] ],np.float32)
retval = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(biggest,h)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,1,1,11,2)

warp = cv2.warpPerspective(thresh,retval,(450,450))

x=0
string=''
for x in range (0,9) :
        for y in range (0,9):
            morph=warp[(49*y):((49*y)+50),(49*x):((49*x)+50)]



            cv2.imwrite('sudokuDigits/cell'+str(x)+str(y)+'.jpg',morph)

            print str(x)+str(y)+" >> "+ string


cv2.imshow('frame',thresh)
cv2.imshow('wraped_ROI',warp)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Things I want to do:

1. As you see there are parts of the grid in the extracted cells, I want to extract
   the exact digit part for OCR purpose.
2. I tried kNN but I get most results wrong due to the blank spaces.
3. I tried tesseract but it failed too
4. http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-1.html followed this tutorial!
5. I want to iterate all the 81 cells and extract the digit parts.

Comment: Sorry, but this is much too broad for SO

Comment: It seems that your digits are printed, not handwritten. If so, a simple `matchTemplate` with your reference digits should work good enough.

Comment: thanks ! but will match template work for distorted images? look the 7 in cell 01 and cell75

Comment: Try and see by yourself. Eventually consider also slightly rotated templates.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry! I'm new to both SO n OpenCV

Comment: You can also remove the white lines that gives you error with kNN ocr by finding the bounding boxes of the connected components, and keeping only the one that contains the center of the image.

Comment: thanks! should i find the biggest contour inside every cell that contains the center??

Comment: The bounding box of the connected component (yes, you can compute the bounding box of the contours) that contains the center of the image is very likely to be the one that contains the number you're looking for.

Comment: ok I will try :) thanks :)